# how to fill successive forms in curl

Tags: php, curl

i need help in filling up a form in curl.
the form i want to fill and submit is http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/Inquiry.aspx
but this form cannot be directly accessed.
For that another form has to be submitted which we do by clicking "parcel enquiry" on 
http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/MainMenu.aspx?c=32

so i have written a script to click "parcel enquiry" but now how do i fill up the form
please help me

the problem i am facing is i use the same variable to POST(other wise i cannot acces that page). the echo shows the form filled but the submit button is not clicked.

please help

Comment: we're not here to do your job for you. show some code and we'll try to help fix it, but right now you're a "gimme the codez" freeloader. That being said, if you can 'click' something via curl, you're already capable of filling in a form. hint: CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I understand what your trying to do and you are going about it wrong.

You are trying to fill the form: http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/Inquiry.aspx and have it submit to the next page. As you say the form fills on echo of the cURL request but it doesn't submit the button.

You cannot submit form buttons etc from wtihin cURL. Instead to do this you would have to go to the parcel inquiry page directly instead of using the form or as most sites do, redirect to the page filling the headers and then make the user press the button themselves.

So you would send your $_POST vars to "http://www.fikeandfike.com/propertytax/Grundy/MainMenu.aspx?c=32" replacing what looks like the `c` with your own parcel number and then redirect the user to that.